# Create Empty folder in S3 when there is no data while unloading from snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have scheduled to unload data from snowflake to S3 every hour . Data gets uploaded to this path : My_bucket/year=2021/month= /day= /hour = /data.csv

[image: Query]

year , month , day and hour gets dynamically updated in the path at every hour run .

Data need not necessarily be there every hour. At that time No folder or path is getting created

I need to have folder for every hour in S3 irrespective of data flowing in .

like hour=1 ,hour=2 ,hour=3 and so on for all 24 hours every time the query runs.

There should be csv file if data is present in table and even if the data is not present path for that hour should be there with empty file

So how should I modify my sql query?

Comment: there is no concept of "folders" in s3

Comment: S3 there are no folder , but buckets you can create a bucket by using the AWS Lambda function, can call it  daily /weekly or monthly

Comment: Could you complete your answer with the query / task you are actually using to unload your data and provide some examples with input / expected output ?

Comment: @CMe , I have Edited the question . please look into it

Answer (score 4):

Hi You achieve this by using one workaround.
Since snowflake will not upload any file if the query return zero rows.
This workaround will copy empty-file with headers only if no data is available.

```
copy into <s3_path>
from (
-- this will act as header for both condition if data present or not.
select 'customer_id','store_id','metro_id','message_type'

UNION

select to_char(customer_id),to_char(store_id),to_charmetro_id(),message_type
from myTable
)
OVERRIDE=TRUE
FILE_FORMAT=(type=csv)
```